# Objective-C: How to add query parameter to NSURL?

Tags: objective-c, query-string, nsurl

Let's say I have an `NSURL`? Whether or not it already has an empty query string, how do I add one or more parameters to the `query` of the `NSURL`? I.e., does anyone know of an implementation of this function?

```
- (NSURL *)URLByAppendingQueryString:(NSString *)queryString
```

So that it satisfies this `NSURL+AdditionsSpec.h` file:

```
#import "NSURL+Additions.h"
#import "Kiwi.h"

SPEC_BEGIN(NSURL_AdditionsSpec)

describe(@"NSURL+Additions", ^{
    __block NSURL *aURL;

    beforeEach(^{
        aURL = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.example.com"];
        aURLWithQuery = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.example.com?key=value"];
    });

    afterEach(^{
        [aURL release];
        [aURLWithQuery release];
    });

    describe(@"-URLByAppendingQueryString:", ^{
        it(@"adds to plain URL", ^{
            [[[[aURL URLByAppendingQueryString:@"key=value&key2=value2"] query] should]
             equal:@"key=value&key2=value2"];
        });

        it(@"appends to the existing query sting", ^{
            [[[[aURLWithQuery URLByAppendingQueryString:@"key2=value2&key3=value3"] query] should]
             equal:@"key=value&key2=value2&key3=value3"];
        });
    });
});

SPEC_END
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As others have mentioned, you can use `NSURLComponents` to construct URLs.

```
@implementation NSURL (Additions)

- (NSURL *)URLByAppendingQueryParameters:(NSDictionary *)queryParameters
{        
    NSURLComponents *components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithURL:self resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
    NSMutableArray *queryItems = [NSMutableArray array:components.queryItems];
    for (NSString *key in [queryParameters allKeys]) {
        NSURLQueryItem *queryItem = [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:key value:queryParameters[key]];
        [queryItems addObject:queryItem];
    }
    components.queryItems = queryItems;
    return [components URL];
}

@end
```

Comment: It work good, but need change part for iOS16:
*queryItems = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:components.queryItems]

Answer (score 77):

Since **iOS 7** you can use **NSURLComponents** that is very simple to use. Take a look on these examples:

Example 1

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox";
NSURLComponents *components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithString:urlString];

NSLog(@"%@ - %@ - %@ - %@", components.scheme, components.host, components.query, components.fragment);
```

Example 2

```
NSString *urlString = @"https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?shva=1#inbox";
NSURLComponents *components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithString:urlString];

if (components) {
    //good URL
} else {
    //bad URL
}
```

Example 3

```
NSURLComponents *components = [NSURLComponents new];
[components setScheme:@"https"];
[components setHost:@"mail.google.com"];
[components setQuery:@"shva=1"];
[components setFragment:@"inbox"];
[components setPath:@"/mail/u/0/"];

[self.webview loadRequest:[[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[components URL]]];
```

But you can do many other things with NSURLComponents take a look on NSURLComponents class reference on Apple documentation or on this link: http://nshipster.com/nsurl/

Comment: Terrific! Exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 45):

Here's an implementation that passes your specs:

```
@implementation NSURL (Additions)

- (NSURL *)URLByAppendingQueryString:(NSString *)queryString {
    if (![queryString length]) {
        return self;
    }

    NSString *URLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", [self absoluteString],
                           [self query] ? @"&" : @"?", queryString];
    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
    [URLString release];
    return theURL;
}

@end
```

And here is an implementation for `NSString`:

```
@implementation NSString (Additions)

- (NSURL *)URLByAppendingQueryString:(NSString *)queryString {
    if (![queryString length]) {
        return [NSURL URLWithString:self];
    }

    NSString *URLString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", self,
                           [self rangeOfString:@"?"].length > 0 ? @"&" : @"?", queryString];
    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL URLWithString:URLString];
    [URLString release];
    return theURL;
}

// Or:

- (NSString *)URLStringByAppendingQueryString:(NSString *)queryString {
    if (![queryString length]) {
        return self;
    }
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@%@", self,
            [self rangeOfString:@"?"].length > 0 ? @"&" : @"?", queryString];
}

@end
```

Comment: Excellent answer, but to be completely safe you should use [queryString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:] when building URLString or you will get nil for the result URL in the case where the queryString is not already 'url friendly' (ex. when the parameter value has a space in it).

Comment: Doesn't work for urls with hashtag (#), where the new query string params should be appended before the hashtag.

Comment: When using ARC [URLString release]; is not needed.

Comment: You should now really use `NSURLComponents` as suggested in Salmo's answer below.

Comment: I don't think this is really a good solution, RFC defines a complex format on `URL`, for example, this solution will break the `fragment` components of the source URL.

Comment: Thanks for all of your comments. I've edited and accepted [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44041883/242933) that uses `NSURLComponents`.

Answer (score 33):

**The iOS8+ modern way**

*adding (or replacing 'ref' value if exists) ref=impm to url which is on min60.com*

```
if ([[url host] hasSuffix:@"min60.com"]) {

    NSURLComponents *components = [[NSURLComponents alloc] initWithURL:url resolvingAgainstBaseURL:NO];
    NSURLQueryItem * newQueryItem = [[NSURLQueryItem alloc] initWithName:@"ref" value:@"impm"];
    NSMutableArray * newQueryItems = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[components.queryItems count] + 1];
    for (NSURLQueryItem * qi in components.queryItems) {
        if (![qi.name isEqual:newQueryItem.name]) {
            [newQueryItems addObject:qi];
        }
    }
    [newQueryItems addObject:newQueryItem];
    [components setQueryItems:newQueryItems];

    url = [components URL];
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Just a friendly post for those who don't want to write boilerplate code while building `NSURL` with `NSURLComponents`.
Since iOS8 we have `NSURLQueryItem` that helps building URL request freaking fast.

I wrote a little handy category to ease the work, that you can grab here: [URLQueryBuilder](https://github.com/soberman/URLQueryBuilder)
Here is example of how easy it is to work with it:

```
NSString *baseURL = @"https://google.com/search";
NSDictionary *items = @{
    @"q"  : @"arsenkin.com",
    @"hl" : @"en_US",
    @"lr" : @"lang_en"
};

NSURL *URL = [NSURL ars_queryWithString:baseURL queryElements:items];  
// https://google.com/search?q=arsenkin.com&hl=en_US&lr=lang_en
```

Comment: Thanks for the category contribution.

Answer (score 7):

I have an extension to `NSURLComponents` that add query item, in swift:

```
extension NSURLComponents {

    func appendQueryItem(name name: String, value: String) {
        var queryItems: [NSURLQueryItem] = self.queryItems ?? [NSURLQueryItem]()
        queryItems.append(NSURLQueryItem(name: name, value: value))
        self.queryItems = queryItems
    }

}
```

To use,

```
let components = NSURLComponents(string: urlString)!
components.appendQueryItem(name: "key", value: "value")
```

Comment: This one may work but it requires adding an extension.

Answer (score 5):

If you're using RestKit it provides [additions to NSString](http://restkit.org/api/master/Categories/NSString+RKAdditions.html). One of which is:

```
- (NSString *)stringByAppendingQueryParameters:(NSDictionary *)queryParameters
```

So you could do:

```
NSDictionary *shopParams = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithKeysAndObjects:
                                @"limit",@"20", 
                                @"location",@"latitude,longitude",
                                nil];
NSString *pathWithQuery = [@"/api/v1/shops.json" stringByAppendingQueryParameters:shopParams]
```

Comment: RKAdditions category no longer available for now.

Answer (score 1):

NSURL is not mutable so you cannot implement this functionality directly based on NSURL. Instead you will have to obtain the string representation of the URL, append your parameters to that and then create a new NSURL.

This does not sound like a good solution. Unless there is a good reason, it is better to work with strings until the last moment and only create an NSURL when you have your fully formed request.