# Parameter in loadWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, mobile

In my app i have this function:

```
- (void)loadWebView {
NSBundle *bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
NSString *filePath = [bundle pathForResource:@"namefile" ofType: @"html"];
NSURL *fileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filePath];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:fileUrl];
[wv loadRequest:request];
}
```

which loads an HTML page in UIWebView. Is possible to pass a parameter in the call ?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: A type of namefile.html?parameter=10

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6309698/objective-c-how-to-add-query-parameter-to-nsurl

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
-(void)loadWebView
{
    NSURL *relativeURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]];
    NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"namefile.html?parameter=10" relativeToURL:relativeURL];
    //If your HTML file is in a subfolder, add it to the string like 'HTML/namefile.html?parameter=10
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    [wv loadRequest:request];
}
```